# next.js getStaticProps Serialize issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, axios

I'm using next.js for a project where axios fetch in getStaticProps doesnot seem  to work even though the URL is serialised in configuration.I tried serializing again by passing the response to JSON.parse but still cant find a solution.

import axios from "axios";
import Qs from "qs";

**My axios config code below:**

````
    const axiosTmdbApi = axios.create({
      baseURL: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3",
      headers: { "content-Type": "application/json/" },
      paramsSerializer: {
        serialize: (params) =>
          Qs.stringify({ ...params, api_key: apiKey }, { arrayFormat: "brackets" }),
      },
    });```


**My category which is passed as a parameter to invoke getTvList or getMovieList data below:**

import axiosTmdbApi from "./axiosTmdbApi";
````

````
export const category = {
  movie: "movie",
  tv: "tv",
};

export const type = {
  top_rated: "top_rated",
  popular: "popular",
};

const tmdbApi = {
  getTvList: (tvType, params) => {
    const url = "tv/" + type[tvType];
    return axiosTmdbApi.get(url, params);
  },
  getMovielist: (movieType, params) => {
    const url = "movie/" + type[movieType];
    return axiosTmdbApi.get(url, params);
  },
};

export default tmdbApi;```
````

**Using getStaticProps to fetch my API**

import tmdbApi from "../../api/tmdbApi";
import { type, category } from "../../api/tmdbApi";

````
    const Movies = ({ data }) => {
      console.log(data);
      return (
        <>
          <h1 className="bg-success">Movies</h1>
          
        </>
      );
    };
    
    export default Movies;

    export async function getStaticProps() {
      let params = {};
      let response;
    
      response = await tmdbApi.getMovielist(type.popular, {
        params,
      });
      const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
    
    
      return {
        props: { data },
      };
    }```

 
**Error :index.js?46cb:602 Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
    |     property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'TLSSocket'
    --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle **
````

Comment: `console.log(response)` what does this return after `response = await tmdbApi.getMovielist(type.popular, {  params, });`

Comment: Doesn't return anything, the error has to do with the response variable

Comment: yes. it returns undefined. when you return `props: { data }` you are actually trying to send `undefined` as prop but before, next.js always serializes those props. since `undefined` cannot be serialized in javascript you are getting that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `console.log` and see what values are being handled at each stage. Instead of `const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response))`, you should be doing `const data = response.data`.

and change `return` statement to

```
  return {
    props: { data: data || [] },
  };
```

Comment: Happy to know that it helps, you should also upvote the answers that you find useful so that others can find them more easily. :)